# How to draw directed graph and mutli graph

Tags: graph, javafx-8

1. Given two points (vertices), say i and j represented by small circles. How can I draw an arc (arrow) connecting those two vertices in Javafx 8? Surprisingly, very little information exists on drawing arcs in javafx8.
2. Given two points,(vertices), say i and j and a number of arcs between the two vertices. For each arc a direction is given. So for example, I can have 2 arcs from i to j, and 1 arc from j to i. How can I draw these arcs in javafx 8 such that they don't overlap each other. I was thinking on drawing each arc as half of an oval.

Normally I would provide sample code, but here I really have no clue how to draw an arc in between two points in Javafx?

Here is an example of something I would like to draw:

[image]

In my application I know the exact coordinates for the vertices a,b,c,d. I just need to know how to draw the arcs (I would favor a faster, simple solution over a pretty solution).

Comment: [ArcTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/ArcTo.html)